# Slack desktop is frequently terminating with no log entries

Tags: linux, slack

The Slack desktop application is terminating. Either it closes after some hours, and I cannot see it happening or it closes when trying to include a file from the local computer. I could not spot a meaningful log, even though I searched under ~/.config/Slack

This happens since the summer, so I suspect some upgrade. Anyone has more information?

More precise information:
'Crash Reports' contains a single file 'client-id' with an id.

The last lines in browser.log are

```
[09/07/21, 12:14:29:134] info: Store: SET_SYSTEM_IDLE idle_taskbar
[09/07/21, 12:24:09:562] info: Store: SET_SYSTEM_IDLE idle_presence

Version: 
  "NODE_ENV": "production",
  "platform": "linux",
  "type": "browser",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.productName": "Slack",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.version": "4.19.2",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.commit": "b92697c",
  "PACKAGE_MANIFEST.branch": "HEAD"
```

Edit 1:
OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

uname : Linux linuxav2 5.11.0-34-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: What is your OS? I have it working with the same version (4.19.2) on both openSUSE Leap 15.2 and Ubuntu 20.04, had no issue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the snap or the deb? If it's the snap, updating to the 4.20.0 release should fix it.  If it's the deb, please submit /feedback to slack

Comment: I am using slack via snap. I updated to 4.20.0 and in effect the problem has disappeared. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.